# Add dynamic closed panels in Bootstrap 3 accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I use [Bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-examples) accordion and I need to add dynamic panels into it. I have something like this:

```
+------------------+
| Panel 1 (closed) |
+------------------+
| Panel 2 (opened) | <-- This is the template panel
| CONTENT          |
+------------------+
| Dynamic panels   | <-- All dynamic panels must be closed, not opened
+------------------+     after they are added
```

The issue is that if *Panel 2* is opened dynamic panels (cloned from *Panel 2*) are opened. If *Panel 2* is closed, dynamic panels are closed.

I want all the dynamic panels to be closed and only when their headers are clicked they will  be opened (like in Bootstrap example). How can I fix it?

This is my jQuery code.

```
var $template = $(".template");

var hash = 2;
$(".btn-add-panel").on("click", function () {
    var $newPanel = $template.clone();
    // I thought that .in class makes the panel to be opened
    $newPanel.find(".collapse").removeClass("in");
    $newPanel.find(".accordion-toggle").attr("href",  "#" + (++hash))
             .text("Dynamic panel #" + hash);
    $newPanel.find(".panel-collapse").attr("id", hash);
    $("#accordion").append($newPanel.fadeIn());
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/m5TMF/)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I just added `addClass("collapse")` on this line:

> `$newPanel.find(".panel-collapse").attr("id", hash)`**`.addClass("collapse").removeClass("in")`**`;`

```
var $template = $(".template");

var hash = 2;
$(".btn-add-panel").on("click", function () {
    var $newPanel = $template.clone();
    $newPanel.find(".collapse").removeClass("in");
    $newPanel.find(".accordion-toggle").attr("href",  "#" + (++hash))
             .text("Dynamic panel #" + hash);
    $newPanel.find(".panel-collapse")
             .attr("id", hash)
             .addClass("collapse")
             .removeClass("in");
    $("#accordion").append($newPanel.fadeIn());
});
```

[Fiddle DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/m5TMF/2/)