# Dynamically add Bootstrap panels

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, dynamic-data

This is the problem. I'm trying to add panels dynamically into my project.

I got inspiration from this [Add dynamic closed panels in Bootstrap 3 accordion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18825975/add-dynamic-closed-panels-in-bootstrap-3-accordion)

But I'm having a hard time to make it do what I want I to do. I want to press "Add stock", and a bootstrap popover appears. You search for your stock (or whatever) and it appears in a facebook like search bar (later problem). And you select what you have searched for. And when you press Submit, the popover closer and a new panel is created, with the choosen name as its topic. But I should not be created at the bottom of the page, it should be created in a specific place on the page. Like at the bottom of a chosen div.

So, a hidden template.

```
<div class="panel panel-default template">
    <div class="panel-heading">STOCK NAME <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" id="popover3"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus marker" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Add buy and sells"></span></button></div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <p></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Notice the button in the template. I asked another question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20904220/dynamically-input-filds for that. It should also be dynamically.

[jsfiddel demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hn9ft/1/)