# Dynamically add or delete accordion panes using bootstrap3

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need help with an accordion pane.
It has two functions: 
 - dynamically add the pane when clicked add button
 - Remove the pane when clicked "X" icon in the pane

Code on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6HHRL/)
Code:-

Html

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle pull-right "></span>
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
          Bill Info 1
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <div class="panel-body">
        This is a form field for adding Bill Info 1
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div id="button-add">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add Bill</button>
    </div>  
</div>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

CSS

```
#button-add{
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

I would like to do this on top of Bootstrap3. If there are links, please post them too!

Thanks!

Comment: add your code on jsfiddle

Answer (score 4):

Here is a method http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/m5TMF/163/
based on [Add dynamic closed panels in Bootstrap 3 accordion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18825975/add-dynamic-closed-panels-in-bootstrap-3-accordion)

I have added a click listener to allow the `remove-circle` icon to handle a click event to remove the panel.

Comment: Yes apologies, it must have somehow gotten lost! http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/m5TMF/163/

Comment: Yes it does at my end?!

Comment: Yes it is the code, perhaps it is hiding behind the `result` indicator on jsfiddle, I have added a top-margin to the accordion here http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/m5TMF/164/

Answer (score 0):

You could use the appendTo method, if it is hard to read it is not required to be all on one line. Check out the [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/oLdecgWDcq) I made.

**Jquery**

```
    var i =1;
$("#click").click(function(){
  i++;
  $("<div class='panel panel-default'>      <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle pull-right'></span>    <div class='panel-heading'>      <h4 class='panel-title'>        <a data-toggle='collapse' data-parent='#accordion' href='#collapseOne'>  Bill Info " + i + " </a></h4></div><div class='panel-collapse collapse in'><div class='panel-body'>This is a form field for adding Bill Info " + i+"</div></div></div>").appendTo("#accordion");
});
```

**HTML**

```
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle pull-right "></span>
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
          Bill Info 1
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <div class="panel-body">
        This is a form field for adding Bill Info 1
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div id="button-add">
        <button id="click" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add Bill</button>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: You have to fork the bootply and get the new link for anyone to see your changes @BarunBashyal

Comment: @BarunBashyal , you are trying to only remove the panel you click the 'x' on?

Comment: I will mess with it and update the bootply @BarunBashyal