# Multple dynamic accordion panes in multiple toggle modules with Bootstrap3

Tags: jquery, dynamic, twitter-bootstrap-3, toggle, accordion

Please help! I am new to this site and new to jquery, so I'm not quite sure the process for getting an answer. I hope my question make sense, so here goes...

This is an extension of [the following already answered question:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24756950/dynamically-add-or-delete-accordion-panes-using-bootstrap3)

I want to have multiple toggle modules on a single page, each with their own unique, bootstrap 3 dynamic accordions. When the `+Add new panel` button is clicked, I want a new panel added to the accordion only within the module that the button is in. Each accordion pane will contain form content only for that module.

[JSFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/mgenest/n9fhLht3/153/)

I have it working to append into the first module, but the problem is that when an accordion tries to add a dynamic panel in another module, it appends the copies to the first module only. I tried appending the panels to the closest class `.panel-group` instead of the id `#accordion` with no success.

`$(this).closest('.panel-group').append($newPanel.fadeIn());`

I'd also like them to expand only one at a time. Ideally this would be per module, but if I can only get one open on the entire page at a time, I'm willing to accept that. I have tried to do this, but the problem is that Bootstrap seems to require the id of the panel tied to the `data-parent` attribute to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: You have multiple instances of `#accordion`, which is invalid HTML. Resolve that and you'll have resolved your other issue.

Comment: Thanks. I named them unique ids. I then tried to append the new panel to the closest `.panel-group` instead but to no avail. Now it doesn't append anything at all. Pulling hair out. (http://jsfiddle.net/mgenest/n9fhLht3/174/)

Comment: Nobody wants to take on this challenge? Awwww.

Comment: Adding:   `$(this).closest('.panel-group').append($newPanel.fadeIn());` on my localhost allows me to append a clone directly it its closest container. On JSFiddle it doesn't seem to work. Weird.