# Add panels to Bootstrap 3 accordion dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to add Bootstrap 3 panels to an accordion dynamically. My (relevant) code is given below:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="queues-accordion">
</div>
```

and the JS code:

```
$("#addqueuebutton").on("click",function(){
    var queue = '<div class="panel panel-default">';
    queue += '<div class="panel-heading">';
    queue += '<h4 class="panel-title">';
    queue += '<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="queues-accordion" href="collapse1">' + $('#queuename').val() + '</a>';
    queue += '</a>';
    queue += '</h4>';
    queue += '</div>';
    queue += '<div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">';
    queue += '<div class="panel-body">' + This is a test + '</div>';
    queue += '</div>';
    queue += '</div>';
    $('#queues-accordion').append(queue);
})
```

I followed this guide - [Add dynamic closed panels in Bootstrap 3 accordion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18825975/add-dynamic-closed-panels-in-bootstrap-3-accordion), but I am not getting the panel to appear on the page. Can anyone point out my mistake please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following line is invalid

```
queue += '<div class="panel-body">' + This is a test + '</div>';
```

`This is a test` is a string and should be added like a string. Javascript will interpret it like a variable (which is again invalid).

Something like this should work instead

```
queue += '<div class="panel-body">This is a test</div>';
```

or store `This is a test` as a variable and concatenate it

```
var test = 'This is a test';
queue += '<div class="panel-body">' + test + '</div>';
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I had one question. If I am adding panels dynamically, the IDs should also change dynamically, right? I mean, it can't be "div id=collapse1" all the time, but collapse2, collapse3 etc...?

Comment: How about using a variable and incrementing it as the panels are added?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am working on right now. Thanks a lot!!